Meteor withTracker and publications and async code
withTracker and async seems weird
export const PageLayoutContainer = withTracker(({}) => {
    const logContext = "PageLayoutContainer";
//  console.log(logContext, "subscribe('translations')")
    let subscriptionTranslations = Meteor.subscribe('translations');
let user ;
//    user =  await Meteor.userAsync();
     let result = {
        subscriptionReady: subscriptionTranslations.ready(),
        user: user
    };
    return result;
})(PageLayout)



-> we dont have the user as it is in a async method but the update is passed to PageLayout and the subscriptionReady becomes true at some point.
I switched to async method in the withTracker to get the user, the result is not more updated (subscriptionReady is never changed) but we have the user

export const PageLayoutContainer = withTracker(async ({}) => {
    const logContext = "PageLayoutContainer";
//  console.log(logContext, "subscribe('translations')")
    let subscriptionTranslations = Meteor.subscribe('translations');
let user ;
  user =  await Meteor.userAsync();
     let result = {
        subscriptionReady: subscriptionTranslations.ready(),
        user: user
    };
    return result;
})(PageLayout)



Did I miss something ?

So far, I am moving all async stuff in the component ( PageLayout ) in useEffect...
